# Use variable as object key

Tags: javascript

I wish to insert variables into an object key structure but I just get the variable name rather than the variable value.

```
var winnerId = 10;
var loserId = 11;        

newMessage.setMessageData({
  winnerId : {
    "status" : "win",
    "choice" : playerData[winnerId]["currentChoice"],
    "newScore" : playerData[winnerId]["score"]
  },
  loserId : {
    "status" : "lost",
    "choice" : playerData[loserId]["currentChoice"],
    "newScore" : playerData[loserId]["score"]
  }           
});
```

Comment: I feel like a broken record a bit, but it always feels useful to point out that what you're describing has nothing to do with JSON. It's just a plain old *object*. JSON is a `string` that *represents* an object.

Comment: good to know thanks. I am sure it has been said many times :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [computed-property-names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
newMessage.setMessageData({
    [winnerId]: {
        "status": "win",
        "choice": playerData[winnerId]["currentChoice"],
        "newScore": playerData[winnerId]["score"]
    },
    [loserId]: {
        "status": "lost",
        "choice": playerData[loserId]["currentChoice"],
        "newScore": playerData[loserId]["score"]
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting  invalid property id (#114) error

Comment: @KeithPower it should work, can you post more detail of your code?